# How to move Repository to another bitbucket account?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have a bitbucket repository that I need to move it completely to another bitbucket account. I create a new Repository in the new bitbucket account, what is the best way to move the whole repository?
I copied all the files to my local and try to push it to the New bitbucket repo, but I was not able to, not sure if that is a correct way.

Comment: What happened when you tried to push it? I've never done this myself, but that seems like the best way to do it.

Comment: Did you change your remote url and push with the `--set-upstream` option?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to copy any files.

First `git fetch` and from there update / checkout all branches that you want to exist on the new remote repo, so that everything is correct locally.

Now destroy the `origin` remote and replace it by an `origin` remote pointing at the new repo.

Now `git push -u origin --all` and you're all set.

Comment: Usually you want `push --mirror`, not `--all` (since you want to include tags). But to set up for `--mirror` you often want to start with a `git clone --mirror`, which makes a bare clone with no remote-tracking names.